# STS4 / Eclipse : nexus + SSL : certificate error

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

My nexus installation has a cert signed by internal org.

I just downloaded latest STS4, maven integration stoped working.

It just won't download from Nexus, and complains of an untrusted cert.
(I don't want to paste the cert name here ...)

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   xxx:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failure to transfer
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.10.RELEASE
>   from ... was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
>   reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates
>   are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.10.RELEASE
>   from/to nexus (???/nexus/content/groups/public/): Hostname
>   xxxx not verified:
>       certificate: etc. etc.

A classic maven builds runs just fine after adding cert to "jre/lib/security/cacerts"

It works just fine with Eclipse Photon. 
Without even using a JRE has the updated cert

I figure that Photon just ignores SSL warnings.

Any idea how to reproduce this in STS?

Thanks